How to write an xml-mapper to get a compicated model with cross-references?
I've tried to repeat in practice the example given here https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#advanced-result-maps.
I was wondering about this part:
<association property="author" javaType="Author"/>
used in this collection:
    <collection property="posts" ofType="Post">
        <id property="id" column="post_id"/>
        <result property="subject" column="post_subject"/>
        <association property="author" javaType="Author"/>
        <collection property="comments" ofType="Comment">
            <id property="id" column="comment_id"/>
        </collection>
        <collection property="tags" ofType="Tag" >
            <id property="id" column="tag_id"/>
        </collection>
        <discriminator javaType="int" column="draft">
            <case value="1" resultType="DraftPost"/>
        </discriminator>
    </collection>

I could not get the way MyBatis understands how to map columns from DB into Author-model object. Yet, I think there is just some magic behind and I will get what I want.
As I said before I tried to repeat the whole example creating DB in MySQL and a test java project with Spring.
Here is what I have so far(getters, setters and constructors done as well):
    public class Author {
        private int id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String email;
        private String bio;
        private String favouriteSection;
    }

    public class Blog {
        private Integer id;
        private String title;
        private Author author;
        private List<Post> posts;
    }

    public class Comment {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String comment;
    }

    public class Post {
        private int id;
        private String subject;
        private Author author;
        private List<Comment> comments;
        private List<Tag> tags;
    }

    public class Tag {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
    }

As far as I can see, there must be a Section model as well and a sub-class of Post class like Draft but I left it out because it does not matter here.
It's the result map without <discriminator javaType="int" column="draft"> given in the original
    <resultMap id="detailedBlogResultMap" type="Blog">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="blog_id" javaType="int"/>
        </constructor>
        <result property="title" column="blog_title"/>
        <association property="author" javaType="Author">
            <id property="id" column="author_id"/>
            <result property="username" column="author_username"/>
            <result property="password" column="author_password"/>
            <result property="email" column="author_email"/>
            <result property="bio" column="author_bio"/>
            <result property="favouriteSection" column="author_favourite_section"/>
        </association>
        <collection property="posts" ofType="Post">
            <id property="id" column="post_id"/>
            <result property="subject" column="post_subject"/>
            <association property="author" javaType="Author"/>
            <collection property="comments" ofType="Comment">
                <id property="id" column="comment_id"/>
                <result property="name" column="comment_name"/>
                <result property="comment" column="comment_text"/>
            </collection>
            <collection property="tags" ofType="Tag" >
                <id property="id" column="tag_id"/>
                <result property="name" column="tag_name"/>
            </collection>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

Select:
    <select id="selectBlogDetails" resultMap="detailedBlogResultMap">
        select
            B.id as blog_id,
            B.title as blog_title,
            B.author_id as blog_author_id,
            A.id as author_id,
            A.username as author_username,
            A.password as author_password,
            A.email as author_email,
            A.bio as author_bio,
            A.favourite_section as author_favourite_section,
            P.id as post_id,
            P.blog_id as post_blog_id,
            P.author_id as post_author_id,
            P.created_on as post_created_on,
            P.section as post_section,
            P.subject as post_subject,
            P.draft as draft,
            P.body as post_body,
            C.id as comment_id,
            C.post_id as comment_post_id,
            C.name as comment_name,
            C.comment as comment_text,
            T.id as tag_id,
            T.name as tag_name
        from Blog B
            left outer join Author A on B.author_id = A.id
            left outer join Post P on B.id = P.blog_id
            left outer join Comment C on P.id = C.post_id
            left outer join Post_Tag PT on PT.post_id = P.id
            left outer join Tag T on PT.tag_id = T.id
        where B.id = #{id}
    </select>

and my DB scheme:
    CREATE TABLE `Author` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` VARCHAR(300),
        `password` VARCHAR(300),
        `email` VARCHAR(300),
        `bio` VARCHAR(300),
        `favourite_section` VARCHAR(300),

        PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `Tag` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` VARCHAR(300),
        
        PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `Blog` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` VARCHAR(300),
        `author_id` INT,
        
        PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`author_id`) REFERENCES `Author`(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `Post` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `blog_id` INT,
        `author_id` INT,
        `created_on` VARCHAR(300),
        `section` VARCHAR(300),
        `subject` VARCHAR(300),
        `draft` BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
        `body` VARCHAR(300),
        
        PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`author_id`) REFERENCES `Author`(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`blog_id`) REFERENCES `Blog`(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `Comment` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `post_id` INT,
        `name` VARCHAR(300),
        `comment` VARCHAR(300),
        
        PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`post_id`) REFERENCES `Post`(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `Post_Tag` (
        `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `post_id` INT,
        `tag_id` INT,
        
        PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`post_id`) REFERENCES `Post`(`id`),
        FOREIGN KEY(`tag_id`) REFERENCES `Tag`(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
    ;

Well, I hope you are still reading this. I would like to get a complicated object of type:
Blog consisting of id, title, author and posts.
Where each post consists of id, subject, author, comments and tags.
Each comment consists of id, name, comment(just text).
Each tag consists of id and name.
So, author should be the same object with not only the same information but it must be actually the same object in heap so when I change something in blog -> author, post -> author should be changed as well. Of course if Blog and Post have the same author(and it's the idea and the problem).
Now if I use the version from the site example I have post -> author as null. When I change
<collection property="posts" ofType="Post">
    <id property="id" column="post_id"/>
    <result property="subject" column="post_subject"/>
    <association property="author" javaType="Author"/>
    <collection property="comments" ofType="Comment">
        <id property="id" column="comment_id"/>
        <result property="name" column="comment_name"/>
        <result property="comment" column="comment_text"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="tags" ofType="Tag" >
        <id property="id" column="tag_id"/>
        <result property="name" column="tag_name"/>
    </collection>
</collection>

to
<collection property="posts" ofType="Post">
    <id property="id" column="post_id"/>
    <result property="subject" column="post_subject"/>
    <association property="author" javaType="Author">
        <id property="id" column="author_id"/>
        <result property="username" column="author_username"/>
        <result property="password" column="author_password"/>
        <result property="email" column="author_email"/>
        <result property="bio" column="author_bio"/>
        <result property="favouriteSection" column="author_favourite_section"/>
    </association>
    <collection property="comments" ofType="Comment">
        <id property="id" column="comment_id"/>
        <result property="name" column="comment_name"/>
        <result property="comment" column="comment_text"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="tags" ofType="Tag" >
        <id property="id" column="tag_id"/>
        <result property="name" column="tag_name"/>
    </collection>
</collection>

I've got post -> author mapped well but it's another object in the heap. So now I have blog -> author(1) and post -> author(2) having the same information but acting like two different objects.
I have to questions:

Why I've got two different author objects from the point of heap and how to change it so that I've got the same author object?
Why the example from site does not work meaning this part <association property="author" javaType="Author"/> ?


On 2, you are probably right. On 1, I don't think that's possible. To achieve that, MyBatis may have to cache all the Author instances on memory and that's just not an option. There is a similar mechanism, but it's only applied to circular reference situation (e.g. a post has a reference to blog). If you can assume all posts have the same author as the blog (which is not the case in the example), you can set the posts' author manually using a ResultHandler (i.e. posts.get(i).setAuthor(blog.getAuthor())).

Hi and thanks for your answer! May you give me more information about this mechanism - "There is a similar mechanism, but it's only applied to circular reference situation (e.g. a post has a reference to blog)." ?

The description of the original feature request is well written although the details are different from the final form. Please ses the test case for how it works. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Wrote a quick demo. It's essentially the same as the test case I linked, but done using the Blog and Post.

Thanks again! I tried it and that's what I got: All posts in the blog have the same blog object in the heap and that's what I'm expecting. Yet, while the blog has Mia as its author and one post has the same author, there are two author objects in the heap with the same info. I understand that it's all about limitation of MyBatis and I'm trying to figure out rules such that I can rely on getting expected result like (Blog has posts that have the same blog) and clearly understand when I get objects being the same from the point of view of information but taking different places in the heap.

I am not sure if this satisfies your requirements, but it is possible to cache/replace the authors using ResultHandler. See the updated demo. If you have to do this a lot in your project, however, you might want to look for a tool that has a concept of entity.
